# Displaying Gridview according to field in database in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I had used a GridView to display my table . What i need here is if the field **active** in database table **Missing** is 1 , then the value is displayed else do not display the value . 
Now this is my code of GridView

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
            <?php
            $cat= Missing::find()->where(['active' => 0])->all();
            ?>

   <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

           // 'miss_id',
            'patron_id',
            'Book_Id',
            'Missed_date',
            'Found_date',
            // 'active',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
```

This is what i used in controller but its not working

```
public function actionListfound()
```

{

```
$searchModel = new \app\models\MissingSearch();

$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('cir_bookfounds', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

}

Now how can i display in GridView .

Comment: show me MissingSearch model

Comment: add ->where(['active' => 1]) in MissingSearch model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView is populated using the data model specified in `dataProvider` attribute of the `GridView`. In your code, this is `$dataProvider`. So you need to apply the filter `active=1` when you are preparing your `$dataProvider`.

**UPDATE**

Based on your controller code, you should be setting the filter inside `search` function of `MissingSearch` model.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Missing::find()->where(['active' => 1]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

... //more code
```

**UPDATE 2**

As per your further comments, you are using the same Search Model for two pages - but the requirement is in one page you will show data where `active=0` and second one with `active=1`. This can be achieved by introducing following changes:

**`MissingSearch` Model**

```
public function search($params, $activeFlag = 0)
{
    $query = Missing::find()->where(['active' => $activeFlag]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    ... //more code
```

And from your controller you can send the appropriate value of the `$activeFlag`. The controller code you posted can now be written as:

```
public function actionListfound()
{
    $active = 1;
    $searchModel = new \app\models\MissingSearch();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $active);

    return $this->render('cir_bookfounds', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Similarly in the controller action of other page where you are showing data with `active=0`, simply need to set `$active = 0;`.

Comment: sm1979  Look i have showed you the controller above , now where can we used filter active=1 ??

Comment: In the controller you are re-assigning value into `$dataProvider` twice. That's a problem. Please remove this line `$dataProvider=\app\models\Missing::find()->where(['active'=>0])->one();`. Then you need set the filter in the `search()` function of the `MissingSearch` model.

Comment: The first line of `search` function will typically be this way: `$query = Missing::find();`. Change this line to include the filter. Also I noticed that you are using `->where(['active'=>0])`. But as per my understanding it be `->where(['active'=>**1**])` because you said only records with `active= 1` should appear in `GridView`.

Comment: i am new in programming could you please solve it by showing me code . Please

Comment: i m still confused

Comment: @BibashAdhikari I have edited my answer and added some sample code. This code you should update in the `search()` function of your `MissingSearch` model. And again, please remember to remove this line `$dataProvider=\app\models\Missing::find()->where(['active'=>‌​0])->one();` from your Controller code (that you shared in your question).

Comment: If this solves your issue please remember to upvote and accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: i have also changed my controller in above question .. Look its still not working ??? if u know just simply code this for me please

Comment: Please post the code for `search()` function of `MissingSearch` model.

Comment: actually the problem is , i used the same search model for two page , in one if active=0 the data should be display there and in other if active=1 . So this is the problem for me

Comment: @BibashAdhikari OK. This can be overcome, but please post your `search()` function from the `MissingSearch` model. Then I can suggest ways to get around the problem.

Comment: $query = Missing::find()->where(['active'=>1]);  this is what i put in my MissingSearch model

Comment: So this has worked but in both page same record is displayed

Comment: Added new suggested code in my answer under **UPDATE 2** heading. It should solve your problem.